Is there a way to join all the mesh created by "Cell Fracture" add-on?

I want to keyframe the visibility of the meshes, it is easier to do it if it is joined as 1 object.

yes you can, but are you sure, you want that? the would move "as one" if they are joined. So no more "explosion"...

Does this answer your question? Animate disable in renders property
